# Impl Send for Bindgen-generated pointer type

Tags: rust, ffi

I am trying to send an FFI pointer type to another thread. The struct it points to has been generated by bindgen [from opensles-sys](https://github.com/AmpMe/opensles-sys)

Here is my wrapper struct:

```
pub struct AndroidAudioIO {
    sl_output_buffer_queue: NonNull<SLObjectItf>,
}
unsafe impl Send for AndroidAudioIO{}
```

The `SLObjectItf` type is an alias for `*const *const SLObjectItf_` whose definition is generated by bindgen. It's a collection of FFI function pointers.

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct SLObjectItf_ {
    pub Realize: ::std::option::Option<
        unsafe extern "C" fn(self_: SLObjectItf, async: SLboolean) -> SLresult,
    >,
    // More of the same pattern, only extern "C" function pointers, no data
}
```

I tried adding `unsafe impl Send for SLObjectItf_{}` and other variants to no avail.

```
error[E0277]: `std::ptr::NonNull<*const *const opensles::bindings::SLObjectItf_>` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:12:1
   |
12 | / lazy_static! {
13 | | static ref engine:Option<mynoise::Engine<Box<audio::AndroidAudioIO>>> = None;
14 | | }
   | |_^ `std::ptr::NonNull<*const *const opensles::bindings::SLObjectItf_>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `audio::AndroidAudioIO`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::ptr::NonNull<*const *const opensles::bindings::SLObjectItf_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `audio::AndroidAudioIO`
```

The reason why I only care about `Send` but not `Sync` is that a single thread (the RT audio thread) interacts with this struct, but it is being created on another thread, hence the need to `Send` the pointer across to the correct thread.

Comment: Please don't blindy implement `Send` and/or `Sync` to any struct. Pointers are not Send for a certain reason. Who is responsible for cleaning or syncing the resource? You could use a `Mutex`/`Arc` to gain `Send` and `Sync`.

Comment: This is realtime audio IO using OpenSL-ES, the struct is safe to send, and should never be hidden behind a lock, there are other interfaces / callbacks that are calling the destructors in the C++ version.

Comment: Since that `SDLObjectItf_` is generated, I must then advise you to only implement `Send`/`Sync` on a high level API layer. You could also include the reasoning behind implementing Send but not Sync into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even if I implement `Send` on AndroidAudioIO the error remains...

Comment: Please also include the necessary parts to reproduce the issue. In particular, that compiler message refers to an additional portion of the code not shown here. You might be able to make a minimal example that runs in the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org).

Comment: I have added the reasoning for Send only, will recreate a repro in Playground when I have access to the code tonight.

Comment: *I only care about `Send`* — but the **compiler** cares about `Sync`: ``the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented ``

Comment: Thanks for your messages. all very helpful. I did indeed confuse `Send` and `Sync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code reproduces the same problem (assuming `Engine` only retains `AndroidAudioIO` at type-level, so that it can produce such a handler at a later date; it works by direct composition as well).

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ptr::NonNull;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct SLObjectItf;

pub struct AndroidAudioIO {
    sl_output_buffer_queue: NonNull<SLObjectItf>,
}
unsafe impl Send for AndroidAudioIO {}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Engine<T>(PhantomData<T>);

lazy_static! {
    static ref engine: Option<Engine<AndroidAudioIO>> = None;
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9236033cb9d56a8678f8b4a764d1ffaa&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

The  issue here is that this `Engine` entity is in a global static variable, which immediately makes it shared across all threads. This requires `Sync`, but `Engine` was not given an implementation of `Sync` because `AudioAndroidIO` does not implement `Sync`. Indeed, regardless of whether the engine contains the audio I/O handler as an attribute or that information only exists at type level, even [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) inherits these trait implementations directly from its parameter type. Quoting from the docs:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Send for PhantomData<T>
where
    T: Send,
impl<T: ?Sized> Sync for PhantomData<T>
where
    T: Sync
```

This is likely a case where `Engine` is OK to have `Sync` (although `PhantomData` chooses this safe behaviour of avoiding assumptions about the inner type). To solve this, first make *absolute* sure that `Engine` is thread-safe. Then, manually implement `Sync` for this one.

```
unsafe impl<T> Sync for Engine<T> {}
```

---

> I tried adding `unsafe impl Send for SLObjectItf_{}` and other variants to no avail.

Well, that would have generally been a Bad Idea™ anyway. Implementing `Send` and/or `Sync` should be done on top of a safe, high level abstraction of your bindings.

Comment: I have not read the error message properly and confused `Send` and `Sync`. woe is me